# I want to put the if condition on two columns and if the result is true, i want to vlookup the value from a different sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I am stuck with an issue and would really appreciate some help. I want to put the if condition on two different columns and if the result is true, i want it to return the value from a table in a different sheet using vlookup. otherwise, it should return zero.

here is what i have tried:

Attempt 1:

```
=COUNTIFS(D2="Dent(isnumber(search("1278",X2")),VLOOKUP(D2,chargesheet!$B$2:$C$37,2,FALSE))
```

Attempt 2:

```
=IF(AND(D2="Dent",VLOOKUP(D2,chargesheet!$B$2:$C$37,2,FALSE),((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("abc",B5)),B5,"")),0)
```

I know i have made some rookie mistakes, but i am still learning therefore apologies in advance.
Would really appreciate some help here.

Thank you in advance and cheers.

Comment: The two attempts use two entire different rows for your ISNUMBER/SEARCH. Finish your conditions for IF/AND and then start the VLOOKUP. Something like: `IF(AND(D2="Dent,isnumber(search("1278",X2"))),VLOOKUP(D2,chargesheet!$B$2:$C$37,2,FALSE),"")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it is simple:

```
=IF(C2=R2,VLOOKUP(H2,H2:M18,2,FALSE),U2)
```